# Trix editor with laravel livewire not displaying database data

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-components

im trying to display data from the database from the trix editor using laravel livewire. The content gets saved in the database but after i reload content disappears from the page even though the content is saved in the database. This is my livewire component

```
public WhyMe $whyMe;
protected function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            "whyMe.description" => ["required","min:50","max:1000", "string"],
        ];
    }

    public function mount(): void
    {
        $this->whyMe = $this->makeBlankWhyMe();
    }

    public function makeBlankWhyMe(): WhyMe
    {
        return WhyMe::make([]);
    }
```

this is my rich-text component

```
@props(['initialValue' => ''])

<div
    class="rounded-md shadow-sm col-span-6"
    wire:ignore
    {{ $attributes }}
    x-data
    @trix-blur="$dispatch('change', $event.target.value)"
>
    <input id="x" value="{{ $initialValue }}" type="hidden">
    <trix-editor input="x" class="form-textarea block w-full transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"></trix-editor>
</div>
```

and here is the view where the component is being called from

```
 <x-rich-text wire:model.lozy="whyMe.description" id="description" :initial-value="$whyMe->description" />
                <x-input-error for="whyMe.description" class="mt-2"/>
```

What am i doing wrong?

I've tried countless things and at this point my brain is checked out. Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changed `:initial-value="$whyMe->description"` to `:initialValue="$whyMe->description"` and everything worked.